# My android app randomly stopped working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I have a bit of a weird situation. I finished coding my application last week and it was working perfectly fine. I launched it every now and then and it worked as expected. All of a sudden when I launched my application yesterday it stopped working. It produces no errors but sometime the screen goes black when I launch the app, some time it freezes and I can't do anything, sometimes it doesn't go pass the first screen.

I am really confused what happened as I am still running exactly the same code. Even when I try my previous backups it still does the same thing.

I have tried cleaning, rebuilding, running from different machines, running on different android device, clearing caches, data, uninstalling and reinstalling.

I have tried everything now but I can't figure out what the issue is. I am still running exactly the same code as it was 1 week ago when it was working all fine.

Comment: hard to tell like this. Any connection with a remote system ?

Comment: if you can post your code and logs. hard to figure out as it is.

Comment: I have so much code, I am not sure which parts to post, and regarding logs there is no error on the log. It the normal log where it says build has been successful, 0 errors etc.

Comment: the log is the android logcat output while the app is running. You got it in Android studio. Try to run it in debug mode, putting break points in the app class if you extended it, then in the onCreate method of the first activity.

Comment: Sure, I try that now